# Database table foreign key in EntityFramework is not set to null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an application that uses EntityFramework 6.

In some part of the application, I am changing an entity foreign data this way:

```
trabajador.Departamento = departamentoId == 0 ? null : await db.Departamento.FindAsync(departamentoId);
```

Where `Departamento`property is an object that corresponds to a related entity of `trabajador` entity.

Look at that ternary operator.

If `departamentoId` variable is 0 I need to remove the relationship, so that, I assign `null` to the related entity (setting to NULL the underlying foreign key in the DB table). If `departamentoId`has some number (the related entity id), I perform a `FindAsync` to assing the new object.

When changing a `Departamento` entity by other `Departamento` entity, it works. However, when assigning `null`, the underlying table field is not set to NULL.

On the other hand, if I change that assignment to this:

```
trabajador.DepartamentoId = departamentoId == 0 ? (int?)null : departamentoId;
```

where `trabajador.DepartamentoId` is the foreign key property created by EF. That works perfectly. I can change the foreign key and I can even set that foreign key to null because it is nullable.

Why that works when assigning the foreign key property but not when assigning the object entity?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely culprit is not eager-loading the associated entity when loading the parent to update.

I.e.

```
var trabajador = context.Trabajadors
    .Include(x => x.Departamento)
    .Single(x => x.TrabajadorId == trabajadorId);

trabajador.Departamento = departamentoId == 0 
    ? null 
    : await db.Departamento.FindAsync(departamentoId);
```

To be able to remove an existing association, you need to ensure you have eager-loaded that association. Otherwise it is #null and setting it to #null does not constitute a change with the change tracking.

Comment: Thanks.... in fact, to get `trabajador` entity I am not including related table with the query. so, when I access `trabajador.Departamento` propery, the relation is queried at that moment, not before. That makes sense to me now. That's why when using the Id property it works, but not the related object property.